# How to disable disk lock?

Tags: filesystem, lock

I am a new Ubuntu user and have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 to my computer.

Now every time I turn on the computer it keeps asking me to introduce a password for the Disk Lock or something before I can put the password for the user. I know the password no problem, the issue is that it's annoying to introduce two passwords and I need to format and reinstall Ubuntu to the same machine again.

Any ideas how to disable that lock?

Again, I know the password but I want to disable it and be able to format the whole disk again. Would, really appreciate it a lot !

Comment: Did you encrypt the partition during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you installed Ubuntu with the encrypted installation. You could learn more about encrypting your disk here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems  Then, the only thing that you could do is backup all your data and reinstall without encrypting the disk (if you don't really want to have your disk encrypted).